# Component identification of an IC

Tags: identification

Does anyone know what this component with the package marking 63 and the "T" next to it is? Is it a Toshiba or NEC perhaps?

It resides on a small buffer PCB next to a 74AVC2T45 device.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have the background to answer, but [according to this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25308/what-do-the-pcb-markings-mean) U means inseperable assembly in an IC package.  There's some good chance it's a custom chip though.

Comment: Sometimes you can google "smd", "ic", "marking", "6 pin" etc, and found a table like this:http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/63. Good luck cheers.

Comment: @KH The `U` designator prefix does not necessarily mean the chip is custom. Some prefer using it in place of `IC`, but `U` is still a common enough alternative.

Comment: @RichardtheSpacecat yeah that's what I concluded.  Separately good chance it's custom or remarked though as there are a very limited number of markings you could make with 2 digits, a symbol and an extra dot.

Comment: Given the application for the part, and that it would look like a very low cost 2-layer board ... not sure if the up-front expense of making this a custom would be commercially viable ... (or maybe that is why the company is no longer in business ?!?)

Comment: @tlfong01 hey that sounds like could be on the right track, TVS diodes to go with the 2-bit buffer ?!? will look into it ... cheers.

Comment: So after some further probing I've attached the measured DC voltages and it dioes look like a TVS diode from ON-Semi (something like NUP4201M or similar). The "M" rather than "T" could be some variation or batch etc. In any case, on this component pins 2 & 5 are connected to GND and Vcc respectively, the others are signals that can be either all to I/O lines or only two going to I/O lines and rest terminated to GND. It looks like the later might have been the use of this 4xTVS in one package.

Comment: The reason for the 1.7V is rather that it is the average of a clock signal that measures as DC (dind't attach a scope to verify though). I suspect there are some clocks signals that are buffered in such a way due to the target head being about 30cm away from the emulator ....

Comment: Most likely some schottky or TVS diode array. Could also be a 2 pair thing with common anode/cathode, lots of different versions exist of those. Measure forward voltage between various pins.

Comment: @citizen Unfortunately it's becoming increasingly common for companies to obfuscate parts to make external repair difficult.  At some large order quantity obtaining chips with your own markings doesn't cost anything and at some larger MOQ it can cost the same to have a custom part made to spec, and may even cost less if you can integrate a few parts into it.  It's worth looking for a part anyway though.

Answer (score 7):

On semiconductor [NUP4201MR6](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nup4201mr6-d.pdf) is available in that package with that same marking and sideways printed datecode.

Comment: Hi yes I did notice that after coming across the table as suggested by @tlfong01. thanks !